# Android Editext selecting multiple contacts from Contact List

Tags: android, android-edittext, contacts

I developed an android application in which an edittext is there for selecting contacts from contactlist and an edittext for typing the message.. In my application the application is working fine where contact list is opened and one contact can be selected to the edittext . but I need to take more than one contacts to the edittext.. what I have to do for that.. My code is giving below..

MainActivity

```
package com.example.sms;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity

{

    protected static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;
    Button btnSendSMS, btnCredit;
    EditText txtPhoneNo, txtMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS2);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo2);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage2);
        btnCredit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);






       txtPhoneNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent it= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            it.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);


            startActivityForResult(it, 1);








        }
    });










        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 

            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();

                StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
                while (st.hasMoreElements())

                {

                    String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
                    if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && message.trim().length()>0) {
                        sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, message);

                    }


                    else 

                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



            }


       }
            });

        btnCredit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, credits.class );
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo2);
        txtPhoneNo.setText(number);

    }




        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

          //---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;                        
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);       


        }








}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `showSelectedNumber` method as :

```
public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {
    // Toast.makeText(this, type + ": " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    // txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo2);
    if(txtPhoneNo != null && txtPhoneNo.getText().toString().length()==0)
         txtPhoneNo.setText(number);
    else
         if(txtPhoneNo != null) txtPhoneNo.append(","+number);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the selected number to a string before you call settext() on textview.

something like this :

```
String str ="number1"+"number2"+....+"numberN"
txtphonenO.setText(str);
```